# How to access PHP array element using JavaScript variable as key?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, loops

So I am trying to make a simple academic system.
I made dynamic boxes which show course information.
Core code looks like this

```
function addcourses(){  //(numcourses)
    var num_courses= <?php echo $_GET['num']?>; //=numcourses
    var newdiv;
    var divIdName;
    var i=0;
    for(i=1;i<=num_courses;i++){
        var divtoadd = document.getElementById('courselist');
        newarticle = document.createElement('article');
        divIdName = 'course'+i;
        newarticle.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
        newarticle.innerHTML ='<div class="box"><h2><?php echo $course_num_arr[i]?></h2><div class="content"><p>Credit Hours: <?php echo $credit_arr[0]?> </p><p>Professor: <?php echo $prof_arr[0]?></p><p>Average GPA: <?php echo $avg_arr[0]?></p><p>GPA: <?php echo $gpa_arr[0]?></p></div></div>';
        call_course();        
        divtoadd.appendChild(newarticle);
    }
}
```

The problem is with `<?php echo $course_num_arr[i]?>` since `i` is the variable from javascript, I don't know how to deal with this.

I want to echo `$course_num_arr[1]` when `i = 1` and `$course_num_arr[2]` when `i = 2` and so on.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, before the page is sent to the browser, and javascript rund in the browser, after the page has left the server. There's no way to get a value directly from javascript to PHP. You have to send the javascript value back to the server with a new request, either a page reload, redirect or ajax call etc.

Comment: you can do that only if javascript code is placed in a php file or it wont work. Make a Ajax call instead.

Comment: Right, I thought that as well. So only available option will be ajax. I just want to make sure before working. Since including ajax due to this seems like silly.

Comment: @Ravistm suppose that javascript code is placed in a php file, what can I do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use ajax call and wants to place the code in the PHP file, your can use `json_encode()` function. Please refer below code.

```
<?php
$cources = array( "0" => array ("name" => "maths","credits" => 30),"1"
=> array ("name" => "physics","credits" => 30));
?>
<script>
data=<?php echo json_encode($cources); ?>;
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    alert(data[i].name)
    var h = document.createElement("H1");
    var t = document.createTextNode(data[i].name);
    h.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(h);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the thing is result should go into innerHTML which makes me have in trouble. so as you can see above code,  the result from data should be here <h2>HERE!</h2>